# How to obtain the SEO friendly URL and not the real one in server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I'm using URL redirection in my site, so in this way one url like hotels.aspx?idh=34 becomes a SEO friendly hotels-from-aruba.h.aspx.

The problem is that I need for example refer the URL to facebook recommendation button or something like from server side code and when I use the request.url method I get again "hotels.aspx?idh=34" when the URL used to access the page was "hotels-from-aruba.h.aspx."

¿How can I get from server side the SEO friendly URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Request.RawUrl, that will be the URL the client requested (relative of course).

Comment: Thanks, the answer was simple and perfect!

Comment: Sweet, I can now say I've successfully answered a question on my phone!